# Control Method Textbox

Tags: c#

any idea how to fix Control method.

'Control[]' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'Control[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
private void TextBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       Control[] txtName = this.Controls.Find("textbox_1", true);
        Control[] txth = this.Controls.Find("textbox_2", true);

        if ((TextBox)txtName[0] != null)
        {
            if (_previewImage == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Area", Application.CompanyName);
            }
            else
            {
                var img = new Bitmap(previewImageBox.Image);
                var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube);
                var page = ocr.Process(img);
         txtName.Text = page.GetText(); // this line im getting an error 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'd need to cast it again... `((TextBox)txtName).Text = `.

Comment: `txtName` is an array.  Do you mean `txtName[0]` where you do `page.GetText()`?  Anyway, if you're always looking for the same two textboxes, why not just create a reference and hold on to it, rather than searching each time there's a click? ((TextBox)txtName[0]).Text =

Comment: @K_foxer9 .From ocr result pass to textbox.

Comment: @K_foxer9 sorry yes, typo, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: the textbox are generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it to `((TextBox)txtName[0]).Text = page.GetText();`

To prevent having to do this cast multiple times, it might be worth storing it in the first place

```
if (txtName.Length > 0){
    TextBox t = (TextBox)txtName[0]);
    ...
```